# convert reverse domain name notation in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In BigQuery, how can I convert Reverse Domain Name Rotation (`com.example.subdomain`) to un-reversed notation(`subdomain.example.com`)?

I see I can `SPLIT(field, ".")`, but the `REVERSE` function accepts strings, not arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have broken the the process out into multiple steps for clarity, but you could wrap all these in a 1-liner.

```
with 
    data as (select 'com.example.subdomain' as field),
    step1 as (select split(field,'.') as field_array from data),
    step2 as (select array_reverse(field_array) as reversed_array from step1),
    step3 as (select array_to_string(reversed_array,'.') as reversed_field from step2)
select * from step3
```

1-liner

```
with 
    data as (select 'com.example.subdomain' as field)
select array_to_string( array_reverse( split(field,'.') ),'.') as reversed_field
from data
```